# Create T-SQL Table Valued Function Error: [Incorrect Syntax Near....]

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

I'm trying to create a table valued function that will do:
[Select *] on different tables, based on a value of the one parameter.

In my code below, I'm getting the error: [Incorrect Syntax Near @OutputTable] and I can't discern why. I have tried explicitly listing the fields of @OutputTable in the INSERT statement but I still get the same error. NB: I am on Synapse.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_get_pipeline_contracts (@ContractDimensionName [varchar](max))
RETURNS 
@OutputTable TABLE
(
    [ContractID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CompanyID] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [ContractName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CompanyName] [varchar](100) NULL
    
)
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (@ContractDimensionName = 'DimContractType1')
        BEGIN
            Insert Into @OutputTable 
            Select
                ContractID, CompanyID, ContractName, CompanyName
            From DimContractType1
        END

    ELSE IF (@ContractDimensionName = 'DimContractType2')
        BEGIN
            Insert Into @OutputTable 
            Select 
                ContractID, CompanyID, ContractName, CompanyName
            From DimContractType2
        END


    ELSE IF (@ContractDimensionName = 'DimContractType3')
        BEGIN
            Insert Into @OutputTable 
            Select 
                ContractID, CompanyID, ContractName, CompanyName
            From DimContractType3
        END
  
RETURN
END
```

Comment: Synapse's `CREATE FUNCTION` [does not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver16) feature a multistep TFV, only scalar or inline TVF.

Comment: Reading the documentation is always a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this a bit

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_get_pipeline_contracts (@ContractDimensionName varchar(max))
RETURNS 
Table
AS 
Return (
    Select ContractID, CompanyID, ContractName, CompanyName From DimContractType1 Where @ContractDimensionName = 'DimContractType1'
    Union All
    Select ContractID, CompanyID, ContractName, CompanyName From DimContractType2 Where @ContractDimensionName = 'DimContractType2'
    Union All
    Select ContractID, CompanyID, ContractName, CompanyName From DimContractType3 Where @ContractDimensionName = 'DimContractType3'
)
```